# How to filter the content of Powershell script output?

Tags: powershell, ansible, powershell-v4.0

I need to capture the result of MSSQL Queries in Ansible output however, there are no supported Ansible modules which help me to achieve this. As a workaround, i have written a powershell script which runs the SQL query and returns the output in a weird format with lots of unnecessary data which i would like to remove.

**PowerShell Script**

```
$ServerInstance = 'serverhostname'
$Database = 'master'
$Query = "DECLARE @sqlVers numeric(2,0)
DECLARE @compatlevel numeric(3,0)
SET @sqlVers = left(cast(serverproperty('productversion') as varchar), 2) 
SET @compatlevel=@sqlVers*10
SELECT name,compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases WHERE compatibility_level<>@compatlevel"
$SqlcmdOptions = @"
-S"$ServerInstance" -d "$Database" -Q "$Query"
"@
Start-Process -FilePath "SQLCMD.EXE" -ArgumentList @" 

$SqlcmdOptions
"@ -Wait -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput C:\temp\SQLCOMPLVL.txt -PassThru
Get-Content C:\temp\SQLCOMPLVL.txt
```

**Powershell script output:**

[image]

How can format the above either through Powershell script or in ansible in such a way that i get only the data in the following way:
name  comptibility_level
data  value

or in short, i could get data between **name** and **(x rows affected)** and could convert it into JSON format so that Ansible could collect powershell script output in JSON format.

Comment: Try with removed `-PassThru` which generates the unanted output.

Comment: @LotPings: Thank you, that one worked. How can i translate this output to JSON now? I tried the following but getting errors:  
$result = Get-Content C:\temp\SQLCOMPLVL.txt
ConvertTo-Json $result

ConvertTo-Json : The converted JSON string is in bad format.
At line:17 char:1
+ ConvertTo-Json $result
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Object[]:Object[]) [ConvertTo-Json], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JsonStringInBadFormat,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToJsonCommand

Answer (score 0):

To much for a comment, so

Redirecting to standard output you are destroying possibly existing objects by stringifying them.

```
$ServerInstance = 'serverhostname'
$Database = 'master'

$Query = "DECLARE @sqlVers numeric(2,0)
DECLARE @compatlevel numeric(3,0)
SET @sqlVers = left(cast(serverproperty('productversion') as varchar), 2) 
SET @compatlevel=@sqlVers*10
SELECT name,compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases WHERE compatibility_level<>@compatlevel"

$SqlcmdOptions = @"
-S"$ServerInstance" -d "$Database" -Q "$Query"
"@

Start-Process -FilePath "SQLCMD.EXE" -ArgumentList @" 

$SqlcmdOptions
"@ -Wait | Get-Member
```

See what Get-Member returns

Comment: Not sure if it is missing something. I am getting syntax error.
Get-Member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
At line:15 char:12
+ "@ -Wait | Get-Member
+            ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand

Comment: So it's clear there are no objects and you'll have to parse text output and work with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLPS Module.

Example:

```
 Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT GETDATE() AS TimeOfQuery" -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MainInstance"
```

### TimeOfQuery

9/21/2017 2:48:24 PM

Check the below links: -

[Import the SQLPSModule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/import-the-sqlps-module?view=sql-server-2014)

[SQL Server cmdlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/?view=sqlserver-ps)

[SQLPS cmdlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/?view=sqlserver-ps)

[Invoke-SQLCMD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/Invoke-Sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps)